# How do you change file permissions to stop Vista from writing to a file in the VirtualStore directory?

Tags: c#, windows-vista, file-permissions, virtualstore

When my program first installs it places a file in the user’s AppData directory, and the program then will periodically write to that file.  The problem is in Vista the writes are not made to the file in the user’s AppData directory, they are made to a copy of that file in the “VirtualStore/ProgramData” directory.  The original file in the user’s AppData directory never gets changed, it seems when the program runs it only has access to the file inside the VirtualStore directory.

Is there a way from inside a C# app to change the permissions on that file so that my program will write to the original one in the AppData directory and not the one in the VirtualStore directory?

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Are you installing your program per-machine or per-user?  Is your installer application "elevated"?  Running as an administrator?

Comment: Yes it is running as an administrator.  I know that I can set the file when it's installed to allow full access, but I unfortunately didn't do that.  So now users have a file that when program runs it doesn't write to, it writes to the one in the VirtualStore directory.  Now I want to turn that off.

Comment: You *can*, and *should* manifest your applications to instruct Windows to disable file and registry virtualization. What's odd is that in case it shouldn't be necessary. A user is allowed to write to files in their own `AppData\Local`, `AppData\Roaming` and `AppData\LocalLow`. The only time a file write is virtualized is if the write first fails with an access denied; Windows then silently tries again. i would figure out why the user is not allowed to write to *their own* appdata folder. The only reasons i can think is that you're running protected mode, or someone's modified the permissions.

Comment: I'd guess the problem description isn't correct. `AppData` should be normally writable by the current user. I think this is an abbreviation error and `ProgramData` was meant instead of `AppData`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UAC documentation [*“Designing UAC Applications for Windows Vista”*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756973.aspx) should help you solve this.

It sounds to me like you need to add an application manifest.

When your application includes an application manifest with a "requestedExecutionLevel" value specified, Vista's virtualization of the registry and file system will be switched off.

Take a look at [*Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) for specifics.

If you haven't previously tested your application under non-admin conditions, you might find that you need to make some code changes after you turn off Vista's virtualization.